# How to keep a process running?

Tags: c++, coding-style, process

I have a process that starts several threads which do some stuff, listen to some ports, etc.

After it starts all threads, the main thread currently goes into an infinite loop:

It's something like:

```
int main()
{
   //start threads
   while (true)
   {
      sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

The extra `sleep` assures the main thread doesn't eat the processor.

Is this approach ok? Is there an industry standard on how a process is kept alivet? Thanks.

EDIT: Some clarifications:

- the threads are listeners, so a `join` or `WaitForSingleObject` isn't an option. Usually I could use join here, but the threads are started by a third client library and I don't have any control over them.
- doing some processing in the main thread doesn't make sense from a design point of view.

Comment: Do you need a way to break out of the main loop?

Comment: Why is joining a thread not an option? You just don't want to exit main thread before all other threads are done. Calling join on all tids will do just that.

Comment: What's going on with all the downvoting?!?

Comment: Why shouldn't you join a listener thread?

Comment: @Stan you're right, normally it would work. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

. Taken partially from the [Linux Daemon Writing HOWTO](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html), I assume you want something like this:

```
int main() {
    pid_t pid;

    /* Fork off the parent process */       
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* If we got a good PID, then
       we can exit the parent process. */
    if (pid > 0) {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    // now start threads & do the work

    for( thread *t : threads ) {
            join( t );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This way the main process will exit, child process will spawn threads which will do the work. In the end the child process will wait for those threads to finish before exiting itself.

Comment: +1: Except given that the O.P. is talking about `WaitForSingleObject` suggests he's on a Windows platform.

Comment: @Nick You are right, I should have noticed. I guess something similar could be done with CreateProcess, though I'd leave that for someone else :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to have your main thread waiting for the termination of the others:

```
int main( ) {
  // start threads
  for( thread *t : threads ) {
    join( t );
  }
  // finalize everything or restart the thread
  return 0;
}
```

If you're using POSIX threads, the `pthread_join` function will do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is an *industry standard*.

What you have is a perfectly acceptable way of running the main thread. However you may want to include a way to break out of the loop.

Other methods include:

- Waiting for all the worker threads to complete using a `join` command.
- Waiting on an `event` in the the main thread which can be signalled to exit the loop.
- Using the main thread to do some of the processing currently done by a worker thread.
- Periodically checking a boolean flag to decide whether to exit or not.

At the end of the day, it depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: If all you want to do is leave the thread running then there is nothing wrong with what you have. If you want a way to exit cleanly (i.e. not through process termination) then you will need a way to do that which your current solution doesn't have.

Comment: I canceled my downvote because I was a bit too fast with it. The reason I assume was "There is no industry standard!" as a first sentence in the answer. Even if the rest of your answer was correct, it gave me feeling of "wrongness". Yes, we might not have industry standards, but there **are** best practices for dealing with processes and threads. Maybe next time be less absolute with statements like that?

Comment: @Stan: Fair enough, it was a bit blunt! I've edited it! Thanks.